# Python 3 Flask - how to send data to server?

Tags: python, flask, server, client

Here is client:

```
data = b'48958695427097097402529251103137444756'
r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000", data=data)
```

Here is server:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask, Response, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def get_data():
    print('Recieved from client: {}'.format(request.data))
    return Response('We recieved something…')

if __name__ == ‘__main__’:
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Client send to server byte string, but server receive only: b''
Why?

And how make server receive entire byte string?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

your `@app.route` does not contain any `method` so you need to add

`@app.route('/',methods=['POST'])`

In order to understand how `@app.route` works, refer [this](http://ains.co/blog/things-which-arent-magic-flask-part-1.html)

edited code of yours

```
from flask import Flask, Response, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def get_data():
    print('Recieved from client: {}'.format(request.data))
    return Response('We recieved something…')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: There was methods, I don't understand why it disappeared after pasting here, now I edited it in my post and it's correct, but code does not work anyway.

Comment: Please remember to click "Mark as Answer" the responses that resolved your issue. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the end of the line in:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
```

After this minor fix, your code should work.

Comment: There was methods, I don't understand why it disappeared after pasting here, now I edited it in my post and it's correct, but code does not work anyway.

Comment: And if you try to send a regular string? does it work?